How to get rid of warning "Undefined or unknown machine type" using IDA Python?
I'm trying to update/port this NIOS2 Processor Module for IDA Pro v9.0.
When I load an elf binary, I got this warning: Undefined or unknown machine type 113. But when I move on, processor module works and I can disassemble binary.
I want to get rid of that warning. Apparently IDA Pro parses ELF file and finds e_machine is equal to 113 which is actually Altera Nios II soft-core processor. But also it is undefined for IDA Pro 9.0.
I have tried set_processor_type(), but it is something else.
I have searched google and there is a deprecated IDAPython function which is loader_elf_machine; so, this is not working for me either.
So my question is rather obvious. I know the machine; I know what 113 refers to. Is it possible to get rid of this warning by using IDA Python? Can I define this number as a machine while loading processor module?
